# Case sensitive query of shapefile in ArcMap 10

Tags: arcmap, shapefile, sql

I am an IT guy, not a GIS guy. What I know about how to use ArcMap 10 I learned from Google. It has served me well so far. Apparently what I'm wanting to do worked in version 9, but no longer does in the same fashion in 10.

I'm trying to select by attributes on a shapefile. I know that in one type of database you can ignore case, but you cannot in another. I don't know what category a shapefile fits in. I even tried Googling that particular question and couldn't figure it out.

Ultimately, I want to perform a search on a particular column, ignoring case for multiple values. I did have this:

```
"STRUCSTATE" = 'IL' and ("ENTITY" LIKE '%City%' or "ENTITY" LIKE '%village%' or 
    "ENTITY" LIKE '%town%' or "ENTITY" LIKE '%county%' or "ENTITY" LIKE '%district%')
```

but it used the exact case I used. There may be any mix of case (including impROper) and those strings could be anywhere in the field.

Help?!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To be certain, use a database function to change to the same case...
File geodatabases or shapefiles, UPPER
Personal geodatabases(Access), UCASE

```
UPPER("STRUCSTATE") = 'IL'
UPPER("ENTITY") LIKE '%CITY%'
```